In Python 3.12, why does 'Öl' take less memory than 'Ö'?
I just read PEP 393 and learned that Python's str type uses different internal representations, depending on the content. So, I experimented a little bit and was a bit surprised by the results:
>>> sys.getsizeof('')
41
>>> sys.getsizeof('H')
42
>>> sys.getsizeof('Hi')
43
>>> sys.getsizeof('Ö')
61
>>> sys.getsizeof('Öl')
59

I understand that in the first three cases, the strings don't contain any non-ASCII characters, so an encoding with 1 byte per char can be used. Putting a non-ASCII character like Ö in a string forces the interpreter to use a different encoding. Therefore, I'm not surprised that 'Ö' takes more space than 'H'.
However, why does 'Öl' take less space than 'Ö'? I assumed that whatever internal representation is used for 'Öl' allows for an even shorter representation of 'Ö'.
I'm using Python 3.12, apparently it is not reproducible in earlier versions.

Since this is specific to 3.12, I read the change log and found "PEP 623: Remove wstr from Unicode objects in Python’s C API, reducing the size of every str object by at least 8 bytes."

Related to the internal representation changes introduced in Python 3.12.2. There might be specific optimizations in Python 3.12.2, such as a two-character string ('Öl') taking less space than a single-character string ('Ö').

@JamalAzizbeigi “such as a two-character string … taking less space than a single-character string” — How would this possibly work?

@KonradRudolph Memory allocation is base of the three polices: 1) Memory Alignment 2)Internal Optimizations   3)Overhead Differences

@JamalAzizbeigi it looks like different optimizations are applied to the two strings, basically I'm asking about the details of these optimizations to understand why the one for 'Öl' is not applied to 'Ö'.

@JamalAzizbeigi That’s not an answer. I’m asking how your point (2) could possibly store two characters in less space than one character. (The answer is: in general, it can’t.)

@KonradRudolph 1.
Memory Alignment: Sometimes, memory allocation can result in different sizes due to alignment requirements. A two-character string might fit more neatly into a memory block than a one-character string with a non-ASCII character.
2.
Internal Optimizations: Python's internal optimizations for string storage might result in more efficient memory usage for certain combinations of characters.
3.
Overhead Differences: The overhead for managing the string object itself might vary slightly depending on the content and length of the string.

@JamalAzizbeigi Don’t take this the wrong way, but are you just pasting output from an LLM here? Because what you wrote really doesn’t make sense, and has a very similar structure to what LLMs typically output.

@KonradRudolph This is the structure that Python 3.12 applies to optimize memory. And surely, each reference has its own value to discuss.

I'd say it looks like the input to an LLM not the output of one?

This test code (the structures are only correct according to 3.12.4 source, and even so I didn't quite double-check them)
import ctypes
import sys


class PyUnicodeObject(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ob_refcnt", ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ("ob_type", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("length", ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ("hash", ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ("state", ctypes.c_uint64),
    ]


class StateBitField(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("interned", ctypes.c_uint, 2),
        ("kind", ctypes.c_uint, 3),
        ("compact", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ("ascii", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ("statically_allocated", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ("_padding", ctypes.c_uint, 24),
    ]

    def __repr__(self):
        return ", ".join(f"{k}: {getattr(self, k)}" for k, *_ in self._fields_ if not k.startswith("_"))


def dump_s(s: str):
    o = PyUnicodeObject.from_address(id(s))
    state_int = o.state
    state = StateBitField.from_buffer(ctypes.c_uint64(state_int))
    print(f"{s!r}".ljust(8), f"{o.length=}, {sys.getsizeof(s)=}, {state}")


dump_s('5')
dump_s('a')
dump_s('ä')
dump_s('vvv')
dump_s('ÖÖÖ')
dump_s(str(chr(214)))  # avoid the string having been interned into module source
dump_s(str(chr(214) + chr(108)))  # avoid the string having been interned into module source

prints out
'5'      o.length=1, sys.getsizeof(s)=42, interned: 3, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 1, statically_allocated: 1
'a'      o.length=1, sys.getsizeof(s)=42, interned: 3, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 1, statically_allocated: 1
'ä'      o.length=1, sys.getsizeof(s)=61, interned: 0, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 0, statically_allocated: 1
'vvv'    o.length=3, sys.getsizeof(s)=44, interned: 2, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 1, statically_allocated: 0
'ÖÖÖ'    o.length=3, sys.getsizeof(s)=60, interned: 0, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 0, statically_allocated: 0
'Ö'      o.length=1, sys.getsizeof(s)=61, interned: 0, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 0, statically_allocated: 1
'Öl'     o.length=2, sys.getsizeof(s)=59, interned: 0, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 0, statically_allocated: 0
'Ö'      o.length=1, sys.getsizeof(s)=61, interned: 0, kind: 1, compact: 1, ascii: 0, statically_allocated: 1

– the smoking gun seems to be statically_allocated on Ö etc..
I think that stems from this line in pycore_runtime_init_generated where it looks like the runtime statically objects for all Latin-1 strings (among others). As discussed in the comments, this CPython PR added UTF-8 representations of all of these statically allocated strings, so Ö is statically stored as both Latin-1 (1 character) and UTF-8 (2 characters).
Also, I should note getsizeof() actually forwards to unicode_sizeof_impl, it's not just measuring memory.

this is an interesting find, but I do not yet understand how the static allocation of some strings makes them bigger. According to the GitHub history of pycore_runtime_init_generated, the static allocations with _PyUnicode_LATIN1_INIT date back to July 2022 or earlier, when Python 3.11 was still in development. However, I don't know how to associate the file versions to the Python versions.

I downloaded the source code of 3.11.10 and 3.12.6 and noticed two major differences: in 3.11, all static allocations are in pycore_runtime_init.h (pycore_runtime_init_generated.h doesn't exist) and the calls are different: _PyUnicode_LATIN1_INIT("\xd6") (3.11) vs _PyUnicode_LATIN1_INIT("\xd6", "\xc3\x96") (3.12)

"I do not yet understand how the static allocation of some strings makes them bigger" – you'd have to step through the source for unicode_sizeof_impl to see if you come up with the same retvals. The static allocation means that multiple copies of the same string won't require more actual space, of course, so there's net memory savings...

The statically allocated strings also contain a UTF-8 representation, which makes them larger. Other strings only calculate the UTF-8 representation the first time it's needed.

@interjay This might be it, with the minor correction that other strings seem to calculate the UTF-8 representation every time it's needed. Storing 'Öl' in a variable and encoding it has no effect on it's size.

It looks like this is the relevant pull request.

@AKX If you edit your answer to include the info about pre-calculated UTF-8 representations, I'll consider it as complete enough to accept it.

@Aemyl Done. Nice sleuthing too :)
